# How do I restore Chrome/Google account stored website passwords

Tags: google-chrome, sync, password-recovery, google-accounts

I just cleared my Google Chrome history. Once it finished, I lost my synchronized passwords. Any help to get saved passwords back?

Comment: When you cleared your history did you have passwords checked? If so you deleted them. Only Thing I can think of to try is Access C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome you will need to have hidden files enabled. And right click on UserData and see if you can restore to a previous Version if not you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try log in with your previous google account to your Google Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for rapid respond i try it several times, nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

Have you only cleared the History? This shouldn't remove your passwords.

On passwords.google.com do you see them?

You may also try to run ChromePass from Nir Sofer which can sometimes find passwords that aren't any more available in Chrome itself. You can download it here: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromepass.html